# How to directly output PDF from a Blade view to the browser using chrome-php/chrome?

Tags: php, laravel, chromephp

I am trying to use chrome-php/chrome to load a Blade view and then output it to the browser instead of saving it.

However using the docs in their GitHub I could not construct a working code that does that.

I tried:

```
public function createPdf(Request $request)
{
    $page = $browser->createPage();
    $page->navigate('http://example.com/path-to-blade-file')->waitForNavigation();
    $html = $page->getHtml(10000);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');

    // How to then use the HTML from the Blade to display the PDF?
}
```

but then I could not use their method to output directly to the browser with `echo base64_decode($pdf->getBase64())` because I have an HTML string and not `$pdf` object, and I could not find a way to create PDF from HTML

Also, is there a better way to load the Blade view instead of using the full URL?

Comment: If you have DomPDF Package installed in laravel then export the data to PDF

Comment: I can't because dompdf doesn't support RTL well so I needed this package because from what I tested it works really well (But so far I've only used it by saving files, not to output directly to browser yet). Or, it should work now because `chrome-php` did the job of rendering it and dompdf just needs to output it and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, I first needed to convert the blade view to raw HTML string, then set the page contents of the headless chrome instance using `setHtml()`, then call the `pdf()` method on the page and output that after decoding its `base64` value:

```
use HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory;

    public function createPdf(Request $request)
    {
        $browserFactory = new BrowserFactory();

        // starts headless chrome
        $browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser();

        try {
            // convert blade view to raw HTML string
            $bladeViewRawHtmlString = view('blade-view')->render();

            // creates a new page and set the HTML
            $page = $browser->createPage();            
            $page->setHtml($bladeViewRawHtmlString);

            // pdf
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');

            $pdf = $page->pdf(['printBackground' => false]);
            echo base64_decode($pdf->getBase64());
        } finally {
            // bye
            $browser->close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to save PDF files in Storage path, downloading it with `Storage::download('path.pdf')`.